# Laravel-Php artisan serve url (127.0.0.1:8000) vs localhost/laravelproject/public

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I want to access my laravel project.I run `php artisan serve` and access the `127.0.0.1:8000` in browser.

But i learned that I can also check my project using the `localhost/laravelproject/public` url whithout running `php artisan serve`.

Question: What is the point of using `php artisan serve`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No point in two different methods like you mentioned run laravel by  "php artisan serve" and by "project url" followed by localhost. But advantage of "php artisan serve" is you can run you laravel project without putting in htdocs/www directory i.e servers root directory. You can put laravel project anywhere where you want and run through the artisan command.

Comment: The part "you can run you laravel project without putting in htdocs/www directory" enlightened me. Thanks @hanumant .  :)

Answer (score 1):

I found some information you may find interesting:

https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-use-php-artisan-serve

But in simple words, `php artisan serve` is an easy way to create a php server and that is what laravel needs to run.

You could do the same with "`php -S 8080` (which would start a php web server (single threaded) in the current directory on port 8080)"

Also if you have already a php server running with apache or nginx it would not be necessary any of the commands.

Hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The `Serve command is just a shortcut for the [PHP Builtin Webserver](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php), something PHP has out of the box, so the point of using it is to start testing your application as fast as you could, you just need to install PHP, Composer and your application is up (if you don't need anything else, of course). But if you already have Nginx installed, there is no point at all, just use it.

It's not wise to use the Builtin Webserver in production.